# I have awarded a bounty,but answer does not appear to be accepted?

Tags: support

I recently awarded a bounty to an answer regarding this [question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/27004/what-significance-does-the-word-order-of-people-tribes-nations-and-languages?noredirect=1&lq=1).

There was a bounty icon at the answer i accepted.I pressed this and the bounty was awarded.There was no icon to press for accepted answer.I notice that the question has still not been accepted because the box is not green.

Why has the answer not been accepted when i have awarded the bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer acceptance and bounties are completely separate systems.

Only the original question asker can choose which answer to mark as accepted. Even the mods can't change this! The little green tick indicates that the answer best helped the original question asker.

Anyone can post a bounty. They are given several choices for why they want to post a bounty, and then can choose which answer they want to reward. If they like, they can post multiple bounties on the one question, though each time the reward must double.